# Transition on load works in jQuery; fails in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, transition

The following setup (see below) *animates* the div on page load using jQuery, but fails in vanilla JavaScript, in that it gives me the animated state **without the animation**. I don't wand to use keyframes or a delay, and nothing I tried in JS worked.

Here's the working version, with jQuery:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#new-selector").addClass("animated-selector");
  });
});
```

```css
#new-selector {
  background: #3a88fe;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

#new-selector.animated-selector {
  background: orange;
  transform: translate(75px, 20px) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new-selector"></div>
```

Here's the problematic version, with vanilla JS:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('new-selector').classList.add('animated-selector');
});
```

```css
#new-selector {
  background: #3a88fe;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

#new-selector.animated-selector {
  background: orange;
  transform: translate(75px, 20px) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="new-selector"></div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/0y7c2wgu/1/

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For the vanilla JS version you might need to wait for the browser to give you the next animation frame using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => document.getElementById('new-selector').classList.add('animated-selector'))
});
```

```css
#new-selector {
  background: #3a88fe;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

#new-selector.animated-selector {
  background: orange;
  transform: translate(75px, 20px) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="new-selector"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Apparently, .addEventListener was the issue.